# Replace GET Variable in htaccess www.example.com?s=bla+bla to www.example.com?search=bla+bla

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a simple question that made me confused for a few minutes. The simple question that I mean is how to change this in htaccess file

```
http://example.com/?s=bla+bla+bla
```

to

```
http://example.com/?search=bla+bla+bla
```

I will be happy if someone can tell me for do this too

```
http://example.com/?s=bla+bla+bla
```

to

```
http://example.com/search/bla-bla-bla
```

Thanks before, I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make lot of sense to change from `?s=` to `?search=`. Better you only support:

```
http://example.com/search/bla-bla-bla
```

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?s=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ ?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: its work but not all, that I got from your answer is `http://example.com/search/bla+bla+bla` that I want is `http://example.com/search/bla-bla-bla` can you help me again?

Comment: still not working. :'( I'm using wordpress engine btw.